# How to select one item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In the WPF `ListBox` control, I am trying to update the `ListBox.DataContext` and select the last one item. But it fails.

```
public void Update_Button_Click()
{
    this.MyListBox.BeginInit();
    this.MyListBox.DataContext = family; // family is a collection of Person object.
    this.MyListBox.EndInit();
    this.MyListBox.SelectedIndex = family.Count - 1;
}
```

But no item is selected in ListBox

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

I tried to update the `SelectedIndex` in handler of `SourceUpdated` event, it also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example and it works fine.  Is there anything else in your code that may affect this?

Comment: Yes, after I remove all the other code, it works again. It due to the Animation of selected item's width. I will try again and find another way to do the animation.